# How to express $\cos(\frac{x}{k})$ and $\sin(\frac{x}{k})$ in terms of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$, respectively?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How can we express $\cos(\frac{x}{k})$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$) in terms of $\cos(x)$?

And $\sin(\frac{x}{k})$ in terms of $\sin(x)$?

*Edit*

Maybe this [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125774/how-to-expand-cos-nx-with-cos-x) helps. Is there a [$T_n(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) inverse? (Link don't say anything about this)

If $\cos(x)=T_k(\cos(\frac{x}{k}))$, is there $T^{-1}_n(x)$ that $\cos(\frac{x}{k})=T^{-1}_k(\cos(x))$ is at least one solution for the question? What is the $T^{-1}_n(x)$ formula?

Comment: Let $x=ky$. You want to express $\cos y$ in terms of $\cos ky$.

Comment: I agree, but I will use with fractions, so I wrote in this way. I had seen some time before the inverse of this question, but I don't know how to solve this one.

Comment: Your problem reduces to find the inverse of the Chebyshev polynomials, but it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) that for degree $5$ or higher, there is no formula to solve such equations.

Answer (score 1):

For any positive integer $k$, the trigonometric function $\cos ky$ is a [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) in $\cos y$.  For example, with $k = 2$,
$$
\cos 2y = 2\cos^2 y - 1.
$$
The polynomial here is $T_2(u) = 2u^2 - 1$.  In order to express $\cos y$ in terms of $\cos 2y$ (this is equivalent to expressing $\cos \frac{x}{2}$ in terms of $\cos x$ via the substitution $y = 2x$), we have to invert the polynomial function $T_2$.

In other words, you have to solve $v = 2u^2 - 1$ for $u$.  This doesn't have a *unique* solution, but we can describe both possible solutions:
$$
u = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + v}{2}}.
$$
This is the well-known "half-angle formula for cosine"
$$
\cos \frac{x}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}}.
$$

For larger $k \in \mathbb{N}$, you have to solve the higher degree [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples) equations
$$
v = T_k(u)
$$
for $u$ in order to express $\cos \frac{x}{k}$ in terms of $\cos x$.

Comment: You added a question about the Chebyshev polynomial having inverses.  Polynomials don't generally have inverses because they don't tend to be one-to-one functions.  The sketches of the graphs of $T_k$ that I linked to in my answer should convince you that these functions are $k$-to-one on the interval $(0, 1)$.  The upshot is that for all angles, there are $k$ possible values for $\cos \frac{x}{k}$.

Comment: SammyBlack, this I already know, but the problem is I would like an abstract way to solve the question, if it is possible. Something like $\cos(\frac{x}{k}) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}f(k)\cos(x)^k$

Comment: Already for $k=2$, such an expression is not possible.  The half-angle formula involves a radical!

Comment: I think find at least one solution (avoiding the other `k-1` solutions) on abstract way will hold to me. I agree that we will not have a defined inverse (like you wrote $cos{\frac{x}{2}} = ^+_-$ above), but $cos{\frac{x}{2}} = ^+$ is a valid solution.

Comment: Well, if we have something like $cos{\frac{x}{k}} = T^{-1}_{k}(\cos(x))$ is at least one solution of the question is I'm looking for. But what is $T^{-1}_{k}$? Is this a well known function? What is its form?

Comment: *Sometimes*, it is correct.  An example:  with $x = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, $\cos \frac{x}{2} = \cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$.  Since, $\cos{x} = -\frac{1}{2}$, using the half-angle formula, $\cos \frac{\pi}{3} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + (-\frac{1}{2})}{2}} = \pm \frac{1}{2}$.  However, with $x = \frac{4\pi}{3}$, where $\cos x = -\frac{1}{2}$ *as well*, the actual values of $\cos \frac{x}{2} = - \frac{1}{2}$.  The half-angle formula is ambiguous!

Comment: The point is that there are $k$ different points on the circle $x_1, \dots, x_k$ such that $k x_i$ is a given point on the circle *for each one*.  (These points actually form the vertices of a regular $k$-gon.)