# integrating an expression with alomst quadratic denominator including Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind

Tags: integration, polynomials, quadratic-forms

As a part of my research (in array processing - the specifics are not too exciting :-)), I cant resolve one specific integral.

Assume $r\in\left[0 ,1\right]$, $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

The basic form  is 
$$
\int_{\cos{(x)}=-1}^{\cos{(x)}=1}{
\frac{
1-\cos{\left(Nx\right)}
}{
N^{2}\left(1-\cos{(x)}\right)
+r^{2}\left(1-\cos{\left(Nx\right)}\right)
-Nr\left(1-\cos{(x)}-\cos{\left(Nx\right)}+\cos{\left(\left(N-1\right)x\right)}\right)
}
dx
}.
$$
Searching for hints, I came across the very informative ["How to expand $\cos{(nx)}$ with $\cos{(x)}$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125774/how-to-expand-cos-nx-with-cos-x) discussion which lead me to investigate the expression using **Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind**, in light of the fact that $\cos(nu)=T_n(\cos(u)),$ but still no luck.

Anyhow, as can be seen in the wikipedia page ([Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) ),
$$
T_n(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} (x^2-1)^k x^{n-2k},
$$
and plugging it into the basic integral results in 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}{
\frac{
1-T_N(x)
}{
N^{2}\left(1-x\right)
+r^{2}\left(1-T_N(x)\right)
-Nr\left(1-x-T_N(x)+T_{N-1}(x)\right)
}
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
dx
}.
$$
Considering also the **Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind**,
$$
U_{N}\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)^{N+1}-\left(x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)^{N+1}}{2\sqrt{x^{2}-1}},
$$
and the equality 
$$
T_{N+1}(x) = xT_{N}(x)-\left(1-x^{2}\right)U_{N-1}(x)
$$
results in
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}{
\frac{
1-T_N(x)
}{
N^{2}\left(1-x\right)
+r^{2}\left(1-T_N(x)\right)
-Nr
\left(
1-x+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}
\left(\left(x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)^{N}-\left(x-\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)^{N}\right)
\right)
}
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
dx
},
$$ 
which has (as the headline states) "almost" quadratic form of the denominator.
This is where I am stuck and if someone has an idea for solving it I will be thrilled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A numerically achieved analytical answer:

sweeping many $[N,r]$ sets in MATHEMATICA, revealed that the finite integral (i.e. integration from $x=0$ to $x=2\pi$) can be expressed as $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}(...) = \frac{2\pi}{r^{2}-\left(N-1\right)r+N} $$ which is very nice and perfectly fits the fact that for $r=0$ it should be equal to $2\pi/N$.

Now that I have the answer, should someone have an idea for analytical way of solving the integral, I will be very glad to hear about it.

Thanks
Itay.