# Can we use Vieta's formula in solving Trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry

**The value of $$\sec\frac{\pi}{11}-\sec\frac{2\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{3\pi}{11}-\sec\frac{4\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{5\pi}{11}$$
is ...

***My Approach***

I used the fact that $$\sec (\pi-x)=-\sec x$$ to simplify the equation to $$\sec\frac{\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{3\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{5\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{7\pi}{11}+\sec\frac{9\pi}{11}$$

Now I tried to devise an equation whose roots are $$\sec\frac{\pi}{11}, \sec\frac{3\pi}{11}, \sec\frac{5\pi}{11}, \sec\frac{7\pi}{11}, \sec\frac{9\pi}{11}$$

Afterwards, I found that the equation $$\cos \frac{11x}{2}=0 $$ satisfy the condition. But the equation has infinite number of roots, so my plan to use Vieta's formula to calculate the required sum did not work.
Please suggest how to proceed in this problem or share any other method.

Comment: You might want to investigate an approach using the complex 11th roots of unity (or minus unity) and expand the power series, and separate out real and imaginary parts. That usually works when you get one of these things in cosines and sines, I haven't tried playing around with it to see if it works for secants.

Comment: @S.M.: You didn't find an equation whose roots are the *secants*, $\sec(\text{odd}\,\pi/11)$. You found an equation whose roots are the *angles*, $(\text{odd}\,\pi)/11$ (along with infinitely-many period-adjusted values). So, a Vieta-like analysis —whatever that might entail— wouldn't help you find the sum of the secants. ... That said, the minimum polynomial of $\sec(\pi/11)$ (ie, the smallest polynomial with the value as a root) is $-32+16x+32x^2-12x^3-6x^4+x^5$. This happens also have those other secants as roots, so that run-of-the-mill Vieta does indeed tell you the desired sum.

Comment: @Blue: I got my mistake, tysm. But how did you came up with the polynomial, please explain?

Comment: @S.M.: *"[H]ow did you came up with the polynomial [...]?" I used *Mathematica*. :) ... To find it "by hand" typically isn't unlike what you did: find a trig equation solved by the angles; your $\cos(11 x/2)=0$ works. Then, the tedious part: expand $\cos(11 x/2)$ into a polynomial in terms of $\cos x$. (It's a little tricky in this case. You'd first expand in terms of $\cos(x/2)$, discard a factor of $\cos(x/2)$, then rewrite even powers of $\sin(x/2)$ & $\cos(x/2)$ in terms of $\cos x$.) Finally, replace $\cos x$ with $1/\sec x$ and clear denominators to get a polynomial in $\sec x$. Not fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{11}$, which is the form of angles we are interested. Then $6\alpha = (2n+1)\pi - 5\alpha$ which implies $\cos 6\alpha +\cos 5\alpha = 0$. Now, [expressing this in terms of $\cos \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125774/how-to-expand-cos-nx-with-cos-x), we observe
$$32\cos^6\alpha + 16\cos^5\alpha- 48\cos^4\alpha - 20\cos^3\alpha + 18\cos^2\alpha + 5\cos\alpha - 1 = 0$$
From this, we conclude that the equation
$$32x^6 + 16x^5-48x^4-20x^3+18x^2+5x-1 = 0$$
has the roots of exactly same angles that you want (with $\cos$) and $1$, so divide by $(x-1)$ and substitute $1/x$ to get $\sec$ and use Vieta's formula.

**Note:** We partitioned $11\alpha$ to $5\alpha$ and $6\alpha$ since we needed a polynomial with (possibly exactly) $5$ roots (and $\lfloor 11 / 2 \rfloor = 5$).

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\cos(2n+1)\pi=-1$ for any integer $n$

If $11x=(2n+1)\pi,\cos6x=-\cos5x$

With $\cos x=c,$

$$\cos6x=2\cos^23x-1=2(4c^3-3c)^2-1=?$$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),
$$\cos5x+\cos x=2\cos3x\cos2x=2(4c^3-3c)(2c^2-1)$$  to find

$$0=\cos6x+\cos5x=32c^6+16c^5-48c^4-20c^3+18c^2+5c-1$$

So, the roots of $$32c^6+16c^5-48c^4-20c^3+18c^2+5c-1=0$$ are $c_n=\cos\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{11},0\le n\le 5$

But $c_5=-1$

So, the roots of $$32c^5-16c^4-32c^3+12c^2+6c-1=0$$ are $c_n=\cos\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{11},0\le n\le 4$

Set $\dfrac1c=s$ to find the roots of $$s^5-6s^4+\cdots-32=0$$ to be  $s_n=\sec\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{11},0\le n\le 4$

Can you take it from here?