# Write $\cos(9x)$ in terms of powers of $\cos(x)$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to expand $\cos nx$ with $\cos x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125774/how-to-expand-cos-nx-with-cos-x)

> Write $\cos(9x)$ in terms of powers of $\cos(x)$

I realize I could solve this by using De Moivre's and binomial expansion:

$\cos(9x) + i \sin(9x) = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^9$

then expanding using binomial and extracting the real part of the expansion and using a trig identity to transform any $\sin(x)$ terms.

However, this is going to take some time to do. I was wondering if this was the only way to handle this problem or if there was a more clever way of dealing with such problems, maybe using polar form?

Comment: Try using the binomial expansion forumla: $(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}$.

Comment: Seems to be a standing problem, see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/117061/19341) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125814/19341).

Comment: As some contributors on this page know well, the full answer was given [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125826/6179) two days ago. In such cases, the *close* option might be preferable to the *copy verbatim* option.

Comment: I just did the calculation you are suggesting, and it's not too bad.  Just to get you started, the binomial coefficients for $n=9$ are $1,9,36,84,126,126,84,36,9,1$.  As an alternative, @pedja's solution below is very good.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

$\cos 9x =4\cos^33x-3\cos3x ~\text { and }~ \cos 3x =4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).  They satisfy $\cos(nx) = T_n(\cos x)$. You can compute them via the recurrence relation.  It's not a short calculation, but is probably shorter than the method you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the binomial expansion forumla: $(a+b)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^{k}$.

Letting $a=\cos(x)$ and $b=i\sin(x)$, along with the fact that $(i\sin(x))^{k}\in\mathbb{R}$ only when $k$ is even, we arrive at

$$\cos(9x)=\mathrm{Re}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{9}{9 \choose k}(\cos(x))^{9-k}(i\sin(x))^{k} \right)$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^{4}{9 \choose 2j}(\cos(x))^{9-2j}(i\sin(x))^{2j}$$
$$=\left({9\choose0}\cos^{9}(x)+{9\choose4}\cos^{5}(x)\sin^{4}(x)+{9\choose8}\cos(x)\sin^{8}(x)\right)-\left({9\choose2}\cos^{7}(x)\sin^{2}(x)+{9\choose6}\cos^{2}(x)\sin^{6}(x)\right)$$